# Foundation 4 suddenly not working in Heroku and all pages error out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, zurb-foundation

Any idea what might be causing the following error? I've made the tiniest simple text-only change in one of the webpages since the last update that worked fine. Any page I try to view gives me this in `heroku logs`:

```
2013-05-01T05:07:07.390621+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/images.
```

I see this error when doing a `git push heroku` (by the way, **everything works perfect locally**):

```
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> WARNING: Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake (10.0.4)
       Using i18n (0.6.1)
       Using multi_json (1.7.2)
       Using activesupport (3.2.13)
       Using builder (3.0.4)
       Using activemodel (3.2.13)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using journey (1.0.4)
       Using rack (1.4.5)
       Using rack-cache (1.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using hike (1.2.2)
       Using tilt (1.3.7)
       Using sprockets (2.2.2)
       Using actionpack (3.2.13)
       Using mime-types (1.23)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.12)
       Using mail (2.5.3)
       Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
       Using arel (3.0.2)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activerecord (3.2.13)
       Using activeresource (3.2.13)
       Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using cancan (1.6.9)
       Using chunky_png (1.2.8)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Using json (1.7.7)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (3.2.13)
       Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Using fssm (0.2.10)
       Using sass (3.2.8)
       Using compass (0.12.2)
       Using compass-rails (1.0.3)
       Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)
       Using warden (1.2.1)
       Using devise (2.2.3)
       Using high_voltage (1.2.2)
       Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
       Using jquery-rails-cdn (0.4.0)
       Using pg (0.15.1)
       Using rails (3.2.13)
       Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Using uglifier (2.0.1)
       Using zurb-foundation (4.1.5)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/foundation-global.
       Load paths:
       Sass::Rails::Importer(/tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)
       /tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/app/assets/stylesheets
       /tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
       /tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
       Compass::SpriteImporter
       (in /tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)
       /tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:2
       /tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
       /tmp/build_2ebj8sbzb7g2f/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
```

And then more of a lengthy stack trace...

***UPDATE***: It seems even when I try to precompile assets locally I get an error:

```
new-host-6:myapp scott$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/foundation-global.
Load paths:
  Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/scott/Code/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)
  /Users/scott/Code/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  (in /Users/scott/Code/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)
/Users/scott/Code/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:2
/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
```

Why is `foundation/foundation-global` suddenly not be found or unreadable?

***UPDATE 2***: Looks like this is just a [bug in the latest (v4.1.5) version of Zurb Foundation](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1792). "The foundation/foundation-global file was renamed to foundation/variables in the recent release. Sorry for any confusion this may have caused." However, if I change `foundation-global` to `variables`, the pages load but the formatting and CSS is all off :(.

Comment: Please post your **Heroku logs** and your gemfile.

Comment: @SumitMunot - the only interesting thing in `heroku logs` is the line posted above. I have to be careful about posting all the other lines.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, got everything working. When upgrading to v4.1.5 of Foundation (I think this started with v4.1.3 after perusing issues in Foundation's GitHub page), you have to remove the `@import "foundation/foundation-global";` line at the top of the `foundation_and_overrides.scss` file.

The reason I had all kinds of layout/CSS issues after doing this is because I had some CSS that depended on Foundation's classes and mechanisms for forms. Foundation 4 has had broken custom forms (unfortunately still broken) which I worked around with my own CSS. v4.1.5 changed the classes and mechanisms Foundation uses for custom forms like `select` drop-downs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that's the sass file: foundation_and_overrides.scss https://github.com/xoorath/TimeTracker/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss. First, the postfixes are not in asset-pipeline form http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline. Also, in that file, the imports refer to missing files.

**Spend some time to read the output logs**, Most of the time we found the trace for the issue in logs.

Comment: This seems to be an assets:precompile issue, there's nothing in `heroku logs` that is helpful aside from what I posted above. Something strange with Zurb Foundation. I didn't think I updated it since my last push to heroku, but maybe I did.

Comment: May be your gem file updated that cause an error, look at your gem specific version on local by command gem list